# How to write a react component that uses a generic predicate in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

i want to make a chip list, which will basicaly take an array of elements, and a predicate by which it will evaluate each element of the array. something like array.filter in vanilla js or lodash.find.

maybe something like `<ChipComponent data={nameAgeArray} predicate={{age == something}}/>`
only the chip that finds that predicate truthy will be selected for example.

**update 1**

thanks guys! so i managed that, now i want to be able to pass it a generic key that will be used as a label. i read something about mapped types but im not sure what im doing wrong.

heres what is tried.

```
interface IChipListManagerProps<T> {
  data: T[];
  predicate: (t: T) => boolean;
  label: {
    [Property in keyof T]: Object;
  };
}

function ChipListManager<T>({ data, predicate }: IChipListManagerProps<T>) {
  const Chips = buildChips<T>(data.filter(predicate));

  return (
    <Grid container direction="row" spacing={2}>
      <Grid item></Grid>
      {Chips}
    </Grid>
  );
}

export default ChipListManager;

function buildChips<T>(data: T[]):JSX.Element[]{
  return data.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <Grid item key={index}>
        <Chip label={"generic label here"} onClick={() => {}} />
      </Grid>
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like below:

```
type ChipComponentProps<T> = {
  data: T[],
  predicate: (t: T) => boolean
}

const ChipComponent = <T>(props: ChipComponentProps<T>) => {
  const {data, predicate} = props;
  const filteredData = useMemo(() => {
    return data.filter(predicate)
  }, [data, predicate])

  return (<>
    {filteredData.map(a => {
      ...
    })}
  </>)
}
```

and else where

```
<ChipComponent data={nameAgeArray} predicate={(entry) => entry > 10}/>
```

Comment: thanks! i added an update, i forgot that im gonna need a generic label key sorta thing two.

Comment: Do you want the label to be a property value of your input? I am not quite clear on what you are asking for

Comment: I want the label to be one of the keys available in the type of the object array, which i will later use as a unique attribute.

Comment: Thanks I figured it out actually thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

you can achieve that creating a generic typed component in this way:

```
interface ChipProps<T> {
  data: T[];
  predicate: (param: T) => any;
}

const Chip = <U,>({ data, predicate }: ChipProps<U>) => {
  return <div>{data.map(predicate)}</div>;
};

const nameAgeArray: [string, number][] = [
  ["john", 20],
  ["bob", 20],
  ["george", 20],
];

const App = () => (
  <Chip
    data={nameAgeArray}
    predicate={(param) => {
      const name = param[0]; // number
      const age = param[1]; // string

      return (
        <div>
          {name} - {age}
        </div>
      );
    }}
  />
);
```

Comment: yup thanks that works, now i added an update about a generic label that i need, and i think that wil wrap it up.

Comment: I can't understand what are you trying to achieve here, why the label can just be a string?

Comment: It's ok , I found the solution, it's not that it couldn't be a string but I needed intellisense when the param is being passed. I used " label: keyof T"

Comment: That will work only if your data is an object.